# Why Android Studio create by default a project based on 'appcompat' library

Tags: android-studio, android-support-library, new-project

I decided lately to move from Eclipse ADT to the latest AS version. 
The first weird thing that I've noticed is that when I create a new project, it is always based on the Android support library even though I selected the minimum SDK to be level 19.
What is the reason for that?
Is there a way to configure it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is mainly backward compatibility. Right now, you may want to make your app for API19+, but later you may decide to lower it a bit down to support more devices, and you shouldn't be having problems with that, if you use support library.
There's also the thing that support library gets updated much more often than Android core library, therefore, if you base your project on it, it should be pretty much bug free.
One more thing, if you extend activity compat for example, the activity checks what version of Android you are currently having on your device and uses core features automatically if available, so it's good for you in many ways to use support library :)